# Modular arithmetic – How to translate "modulus/ moduli"?

Tags: english-to-german, mathematics

The english Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic):

> In mathematics, modular arithmetic is a system of arithmetic for integers, where numbers "wrap around" upon reaching a certain value—the **modulus** (plural **moduli**).

I have doubts whether in German this word would translate to **Modulus** (plural **Moduli**) or **Modul** (plural **Moduln**).

As on a quick research I could not find neither version it also seems likely that the word is avoided altogether by only referring to the operation as in:

> Es ist *a* kongruent zu *b* modulo *m*.

Which version is it?

Comment: I would consider *modulus* as a non-translated English substantive, for which a perfect translation exists, and therefore avoid to use it in German.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example expression from modular arithmetic:

> *x*² ≡ *y*    (mod *n*)

It is read aloud as

> X Quadrat ist äquivalent zu Y **modulo** N.

Here, **modulo** denotes the [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), and *n* is referred to as *der **Modulus***, the plural of which is *die **Moduli***. Actually, *modulo* is the ablative case of the Latin word *modulus*. Gauß himself used *Modulus/ Moduli*, not only in his Latin work *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, but also in German texts (see, for example, various passages in [Carl Friedrich Gauß. Werke. Band II](https://books.google.de/books?id=fDMAAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Modulus&f=false)). Nowadays, some people refer to *n* as *der **Modul*** (with stress on the first syllable), the plural of which is *die **Moduln***. For example, in his famous book *„Das ist o. B. d. A. trivial!“* Beutelspacher (2009, 9th edt., p. 81) writes:

> „Man nennt die Zahl *n* den Modul. Früher hieß dies (auf Lateinisch) der modulus; daher kommt der traditionelle Plural die Moduli; heute kann man aber
>   auch Moduln sagen.“

Personally, I stick with Gauß and use *Modulus/ Moduli*, when I mean the concept in modular arithmetic. In the realm of linear algebra, I use [*Modul/ Moduln*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) to denote Abelian groups that are acted upon by elements of a commutative ring.

As a last point, there is the term *das **Modul*** (with stress on the second syllable), the plural of which is *die **Module***. Outside of mathematics, it is used to refer to any kind of modular unit.

Comment: Modulus/Moduli is the correct English term. Are you sure it's also used in German? Because the German examples I found use Modul/Moduln, [e.g.](http://www.mathematik-netz.de/pdf/Moduln.pdf) »die damit begann, dass Gauß die Bezeichnung a ≡ b mod m - gelesen: a kongruent b modulo m - einführte [...] Als "Modul" wurde zunächst die Zahl m [...]« (Page 2)

Comment: I personally like the version Modulus/Moduli better, especially to avoid any confusion with the other kind of Modul you mentioned (this one https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modul_(Mathematik)).
But probably Beutelspacher is right about the fact that it is antiquated or latinish.

Comment: *Äquivalent*, really? I only know it as *congruence*, so I would expect *congruent* or *kongruent*. And in German, I also use *Modulus/Moduli*. *Modul/Moduln* sounds wrong.

Comment: @FloraHerzner: antiquated, perhaps, but I would call it better compatible with international terms (modulus). And it distinguishes it from the other meaning, which is called module, not modulus, in English, i.e. also differently. I think the use of Modul in German for what is called modulus in English is probably due to confusion with module and it somehow stuck.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ich kenne beides, zumal die Kongruenz modulo _n_ auf den ganzen Zahlen eine Äquivalenzrelation ist. Aber ich gebe zu: _kongruent_ wird häufiger gesagt.

Comment: *Mod* isn't an operator in the mathematical statement "x² ≡ y    (mod n)" since an operator has inputs and an output. However it is true that a program would need to use the *mod* operator to write this statement in a way a computer could understand: "x² mod n = y mod n". Here *mod* is an operator as it has an output. I am writing a separate answer to discuss whether *modulo* is the correct name and thus how to translate it.

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is indeed

> Modul (pl. Moduln)

[duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Modul_Verhaeltnis_Divisor)

But i have also found a [script](http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/%7Ekonen/DisMa/DisMa-Kap1.pdf) with another plural form

> Modul (pl. Module)

Quoting page 7

> Sei ℤ<sub>m</sub> = {0,1,...,m-1}. Der ganzzahlige Rest r bei Division von a durch m
>
> r = a mod m
>
> ist diejenige Zahl r ∈ ℤ<sub>m</sub>, für die a – r ein Vielfaches von m ist.
>
> Die Zahl m heißt Modul.

Page 12

> Der Satz gilt nur, wenn die Module teilerfremd sind. Sind sie nicht teilerfremd, so kann das System keine oder mehrere Lösungen in Zm haben.

**Edit**

After looking at some [other](http://www.math.uni-bremen.de/didaktik/ma/ralbers/Veranstaltungen/ArithmAP0809/Material/SkriptWiSe4_KongMod.pdf) [scripts](http://www.mathematik-netz.de/pdf/Moduln.pdf)

> Für alle a,b ∈ ℤ und jeden Modul m ∈ ℕ gilt:
>
> Zu den wichtigsten algebraischen Konstrukten gehören [...] inbesondere die Moduln

and my own old math notes I think it's as Duden says:

> Der Modul, pl: Die Moduln

Comment: Was ist mit "Modulo" (Ez.)?

Comment: @userunknown m.W. bezeichnet Modulo nur die Rechenoperation (mod)

Comment: Die deutsche [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modul_(Mathematik)) unterstützt auch die Variante "Modul, pl. Moduln".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The following statement most likely refers to the other kind of mathematical object called "Modul".

"Zu den wichtigsten algebraischen Konstrukten gehören [...] inbesondere die Moduln" 

But as the Duden uses Modul in the modular arithmetic way, your answer is definitely correct. On the other hand I try to avoid confusion of modular arithmetic with the algebraic object, and will stick to the Gauss version. @IQV  That "Modul" is also not the one from modular arithmetic, so I think my concern is justified.

Answer (score 1):

The German term for this is *Modul*. You can find it in many German books on number theory, and as an example I list here a [section](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-47536-8_8) of a famous book by Adolf Hurwitz, which is called *Die ganzen Quaternionen nach einer ungeraden Zahl als Modul*.

Note that the English word *modulus* and German *Modul* have several other meanings in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about *modulo* which is getting confused with *modulus*.

> x² ≡ y modulus n

does not make grammatical sense. (Just try to explain the use of the noun *modulus* in that sentence.) So to make sense you have to understand something like

> x² ≡ y  *with modulus of n*

This is a bit clumsy but as *modulus* was Latin and all mathematicians had learnt Latin anyway the solution was simple. Just say

> x² ≡ y modulo n

Here *modulo* is ablative which can be used without a preposition to mean "with modulus" and since numbers don't usually decline (and certainly not when written as *6* or *n*) we can treat *n* as genitive and translate as *of n* if we choose.

So when translating into German you either need a preposition, which is clumsy, or to stick to Latin.

I would say *modulus arithmetic* but *modulo arithmetic* makes some sense as it means "arithmetic with modulus". I don't think *modulo operator* makes sense. I would say *modulus operator*. I think computer scientists invented the *modulo operator* because of their well known lack of knowledge of Latin grammar as [shown here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/viruses-or-virii).

Comment: You are certainly right; nonetheless, this is more a comment than an answer to the OP's "question": _I have doubts whether in German this word would translate to **Modulus** (plural **Moduli**) or **Modul** (plural **Moduln**)._