# Warum gibt es das Modul und der Modul?

Tags: etymology

Warum gibt es "das Modul" (n) und "der Modul" (m)? Warum gibt es die Maskuline Form, und warum ist davon der Plural "die Moduln"? Ich hab bisher keine Informationen darüber gefunden, und Google suchen haben schnell zu sehr unrelevanten Ergebnissen geführt.

Comment: Abgesehen vom Geschlecht ist auch die Betonung anders: Das Modúl, der Módul. Die m. Form scheint es nur im mathematisch-technischen Kontext zu geben, ähnlich wie bei das oder der Kalkül.

Comment: Aber worauf geht der Modul zurück?

Comment: Verwandte englische [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50627/1696).

Comment: Obwohl hier vorallem Latein der Vorzugzuggeben ist, ist m- als Praefix im Semitischen nicht zu übersehen, welcher zufällig Nomen bildet (wie Mujahedin neben Jihadi, besseres Beispiel fällt mir grad nicht). Das andere Teil sieht mir ungefähr wie was Persisches aus, weil ich grad etwas Kurdisch gelernt. Ergo, war wohl Fönizisch.

Answer (score 1):

Beide Worte gehen mittelbar oder unmittelbar auf das lateinische *modus* "das Maß, der Takt, die Art und Weise" (vgl. [*modus operandi*](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Modus_Operandi)) zurück. Das zugehörige lateinische Verb ist [*modulārī*](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/latein-deutsch/modulari) "nach dem Takt abmessen, zum Gesang den Takt mit den Füßen schlagen". Ein Blick in die Herkunfts- und Bedeutungsunterschiede liefert Indizien für Frage, warum die Genera verschieden sind. (Leider habe ich keine definitive Quelle gefunden, die deine Frage beantwortet.)

## Modul, n.

Die neutrale Form *das Modul*, [moˈduːl], Plural: *Module* hat die Bedeutung "Einheit, Untereinheit, Komponente". Das zugehörige Adjektiv ist *modularisiert*. Der [Online-Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Modul_Element_Lehreinheit) gibt als Herkunft englisches *module* an, das seinerseits von *modulus*, dem Diminutiv (der Verkleinerungsform) von lat. *modus* stammt. In der im Verb *modulari* sichtbaren Bedeutung von *modus* "Takt" scheint mir der semantische Kern von "Untereinheit, Komponente" bereits angelegt.

## Modul, m.

Die maskuline Form *der Modul* [ˈmoːdʊl], Plural: *Moduln* [ˈmoːdʊln] hat 3 Bedeutungen:

(1) Ein charakteristisches Maß für ein Zahnrad:

> Der *Modul* oder die *Durchmesserteilung* ist ein Maß für die Größe der Zähne von Zahnrädern. Sein Wert basiert typisch auf der Längeneinheit Millimeter und ergibt sich aus dem Teilkreisdurchmesser d geteilt durch die Zähnezahl z.

Damit zwei Zahnräder zusammenpassen und ineinander greifen (damit sie "kämmen"), müssen ihre Moduln übereinstimmen.<sup>[1](https://www.lehrerfreund.de/technik/1s/zahnradberechnung-1/www.lehrerfreund.de/technik/1s/stirnraeder-einstufiges-getriebe)</sup> Der Modul ist damit eine entscheidende Kenngröße eines Zahnrads.

(2) In der Mathematik bezeichnet *Modul* eine algebraische Struktur. Dem Namen des mathematischen Begriffs [*Modul, m.*](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Modul_(Mathematik)) liegt vermutlich die *Modulo-Operation* zugrunde - *Moduln* können als Verallgemeinerungen von zyklischen Gruppen mit Primzahlordnung aufgefasst werden. Diese sind gerade die Gruppen, die entstehen, wenn man alle Elemente einer [Restklasse](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Restklasse)  als äquivalent auffasst, also alle Zahlen, die bezüglich eines festen Divisors den gleichen Rest (also den gleichen Modulo-Wert) haben:<sup>[[2]](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Restklasse)</sup>

> Die Restklasse von *a modulo m*, geschrieben
> *a* + *m*ℤ
> ist die Äquivalenzklasse von *a* bezüglich der Kongruenz modulo *m*, also die Menge der Ganzzahlen, die bei Division durch *m* den gleichen Rest wie *a* ergeben.

Die Herleitung des Namens des mathematischen Begriffs *der Modul* aus dem Namen der *Modulo-Operation* ist also semantisch schlüssig. Sie harmoniert darüberhinaus auch mit der Betonung, mit dem langen o. Leider habe ich keine Belege für diese Begriffsgeschichte gefunden.

Der moderne Begriff (hier nicht im sprachlichen Sinn, sondern im mathematischen Sinn, die mathematische Definition) des *Moduls* ist von Emmy Noether 1921 in ihrer Arbeit [*Idealtheorie in Ringbereichen* in den *Mathematischen Annalen*](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002267829) eingeführt worden. Darin wird allerdings nicht das Wort *Modul* eingeführt, dieses existierte schon vorher. Noether verwendet hier das Wort in der maskulinen Form und mit dem Plural *Moduln*:<sup>[3](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0083?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B60%5D,%22panX%22:0.489,%22panY%22:0.689,%22view%22:%22thumbnails%22,%22zoom%22:0.395%7D)</sup>

> **Ausdehnung der Untersuchung auf Moduln. Anzahlgleichheit der Komponenten bei Zerlegungen in irreduzible Moduln.**
> Wir zeigen jetzt, daß der Inhalt der drei ersten Paragraphen, der sich auf irreduzible, nicht auf primäre und Prim-Ideale bezieht, unter geringeren Voraussetzungen bestehen bleibt. Diese Paragraphen benutzen nämlich das kommutative Gresetz der Multiplikation nicht und beziehen sich nur auf die Eigenschaft der Ideale, Moduln zu sein, bleiben also halten für Moduln in bezug auf nicht-kommutative Bereiche, die jetzt zu delSnieren sind. DerDefinition der Moduln ist ein Doppelbereich (*Σ*,*T*) zugrunde zu legen [...]

(3) In der Materialforschung werden verschiedene Werkstoffcharakteristika als [*Modul*](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Elastizit%C3%A4tsmodul) bezeichnet.

---

Diese Bedeutungs- und Herkunftsübersicht liefert Indizien für die unterschiedliche Bestimmung des Genus:

*Modul, n.* wird mit kurzem o gesprochen. Dies entspricht dem englischen Wort *module*, von dem *Modul, n.* ins Deutsche entlehnt wurde. Die Aussprache von engl. *module* entspricht ihrerseits der Aussprache des lateinischen Lehnswortes *modulus*.

*Modul, m.* wird mit langem o gesprochen. Der Online-Duden gibt an, dass es direkt aus dem lateinischen entlehnt sei, von *modulus*. Daran bestehen allerdings Zweifel. Wahrscheinlicher erscheint mir, dass *Modul, m.* eine Relatinisierung von althochdeutschem bzw. [mittelhochdeutschem *Model, m.*](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=LexerN&lemid=M00548#3) "Form, Maß, Muster, Vorbild" (vgl. [*modeln*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/modeln), *ummodeln*), welches im neuhochdeutschen allerdings laut Grimmschem Wörterbuch) auch in neutraler Form existiert hat. Aussprache und Geschlecht hätten sich dann nach diesem Vorbild gerichtet. Das scheint insbesondere für *Modul, m.* (1) plausibel. Auch die eigentümliche Pluralbildung auf *-n*, *Moduln*, wäre dann als ein Überbleibsel des Plurals *Modeln* von ahd. bzw. mhd. *Model, m.* aufzufassen.

Diese Harmonie von Bedeutung, Betonung, Geschlecht und Pluralbildung halte ich für ein starkes Indiz für diese Hypothese. Da Model bereits im Deutschen existiert hat, *Modul* allerdings weder im Althochdeutschen noch im Mittelhochdeutschen aufzutauchen scheint (gemäß [Steinmeyer](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB) und [Lexer](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/#0)), halte ich es für viel wahrscheinlicher, dass *Modul, m.* auf *Model, m.* zurückgeht, und die Angabe im Duden hier etwas ungenau ist.

Die maskulinen Formen sind einander semantisch näher als der neutralen Form: Die Bedeutungen des maskulinen Wortes liegen alle im semantischen Feld von "Maß, Relation",<sup>3</sup> das Wort mit neutralem Genus hat eher die Bedeutung "Abschnitt, Teil, Untereinheit". Es ist also auch vorstellbar, dass die maskulinen Formen auf einander Einfluss genommen haben, und dass gerade eine begriffliche Abgrenzung zu *Modul, n.* gesucht wurde. Oben habe ich erläutert, warum *Modul, m.* (2) auf die Modulo-Operation zurückgehen *könnte*. Es könnte aber auch sein, dass es einfach *Modul, m.* (1) nachgebildet ist.

---

<sup>3</sup> Gerade zwischen (1) und (2)  das sehe ich persönlich eine sehr starke semantische Nähe, weil zwei ineinander greifende Zahnräder für mich eine hervorragende bildliche Darstellung einer zyklischen Gruppe bilden. Aber das ist wohl eher eine Privat-Assoziation, und in der Begriffsgeschichte wahrscheinlich irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Wörter, die in mehreren Genera (und unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen) auftreten, sind im Deutschen nicht besonders selten.

*Das* Modul (im Sinne von *Komponente*, z.B. "das Modul einer Raumstation" oder "ein Software-Modul") scheint ein aus dem Englischen eingewandertes Fremdwort zu sein. Das englische Fremdword "module" scheint wiederum abgeleitet von lat. *modulus* (Diminuitiv von *modus*), "Maßchen".

*Der* Modul (im Sinne von *Verhältnis*, z.B. "der Modul eines Zahnrades") scheint ein direkt aus dem Lateinischen übernommenes Fremdwort abgeleitet von "modus" ("Maß") zu sein.

Durch die zwei verschiedenen Einwanderungswege der beiden Fremdworte entstand anscheinend die jeweilige Spezialisierung des ursprünglich sehr allgemeinen Begriffes.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Sowohl der Duden als auch Wiktionary und weitere Wörterbücher scheinen sich darüber einig zu sein, dass es so ist. Und damit sprechen sie (offensichtlich) gegen die Annahme, dass *der Modul* von Modulus abgeleitet ist. (Es spricht i.Ü. wenig dafür, dass man ein *Verhältnis* von zwei Größen ausgerechnet mit einem Diminuitiv ausdrücken sollte)

Comment: Und woher kommt der Plural "moduln"?

Comment: Ich denke, es würde die Qualität der Antwort erhöhen, wenn du die genauen Quellen in der Antwort nennst.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Was genau ist an "Duden" und "Wiktionary" ungenau?

Comment: Ich meine vor Allem, die Informationen zu den Quellen wären besser in der Antwort aufgehoben, nicht in den Kommentaren. In deiner Antwort ist überdies unklar, welche Information aus den Quellen kommt, und welche auf deiner Argumentation beruhen ("anscheinend"). Und natürlich würde eine genaue Zitation das Lemma beinhalten, aber das ergibt sich ja hier von selbst. Beim Duden ist es noch ratsam, die Ausgabe und das genaue Wörterbuch anzugeben denn der Duden ist eine Sammelbezeichnung verschiedener Wörterbücher.

Comment: Die genau  Quelle ist insbesondere deshalb relevant, weil zumindest der Online-Duden deiner Aussage, dass die zweite Form direkt auf lat. _modus_ zurückgeht, gerade widerspricht, und angibt, dass sie auf lateinisch modulus zurückgeht: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Modul_Verhaeltnis_Divisor Der Duden scheint da also seine Meinung in den verschiedenen Ausgaben geändert zu haben...

Comment: Von wegen Fachsprache, *ummodeln* und *Kuddelmuddel* noch nie gehört?